# Parsing Tweets with akka-streams

Tags: twitter, akka, akka-stream

Im using the following code to connect to Twitter and get Tweets, however Im not able to create `JsValue`. If only `map` with `byteString.utf8String` I can see the strings. But when I add framing i get an error:

```
Read 7925 bytes which is more than 1000 without seeing a line terminator
```

No matter how long i make the input im still getting this error. What do I need to  change to get a stream of `JsValue` in my websocket?

Information about how one is expected to consume twitter streams can be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/processing)

```
@Singleton
class TwitterController @Inject() (ws: WSClient, conf: Configuration) {

  def tweets = WebSocket.accept[JsValue,JsValue] { implicit request =>
    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, queryToSource("cat"))
  }

  def queryToSource(keyword: String): Source[JsValue, NotUsed] = {
    val url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json"
    credentials.map { case (consumerKey, requestToken) =>

      val request = ws.url(url)
        .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
        .withQueryString("track" -> keyword)
        .withMethod("GET")

      streamResponse(request)
        .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\r\n"), maximumFrameLength = 1000, allowTruncation = true))
        .map { byteString =>
          Json.parse(byteString.utf8String)
//        byteString.utf8String
        }
    } getOrElse {
      Source.single(Json.parse("Twitter credentials missing"))
    }
  }

  private def streamResponse(request:WSRequest): Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = Source.fromFuture(request.stream()).flatMapConcat(_.body)

  lazy val credentials: Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] = for {
    apiKey <- conf.getString("twitter.apiKey")
    apiSecret <- conf.getString("twitter.apiSecret")
    token <- conf.getString("twitter.token")
    tokenSecret <- conf.getString("twitter.tokenSecret")
  } yield (
    ConsumerKey(apiKey, apiSecret),
    RequestToken(token, tokenSecret)
    )
}
```

Comment: Is it delimited with "\r\n"'s then?

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the comment.